# Laravel: add product sizes relation with a price pivot

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying this for a while now and I can't seem to figure it out.

So I have a Products and a Sizes table with a belongs to many relation.

So in my model I have:

```
public function sizes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'size_product')->withPivot('price');
}
```

My forms looks like this:

[image: My forms looks like this (don't loog at the styles)]

My blade looks like this:

```
<h2 class="fields-holder__title">Sizes</h2>
@foreach($sizes as $size)
    <div class="field-holder__container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sizes[]" value="{{ $size->id }}">
        <input type="text" name="prices[]" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And in my controller on post I do:

```
// add and remove sizes pivot
$sizes = [];
foreach ($request->sizes as $size) {
    array_push($sizes, $size);
}
$product->sizes()->sync($sizes);
```

But how do I save the prices?

I know you can do this in Laravel:

```
$product->sizes()->sync($size, ['price' => $price]);
```

But how do I get this in the foreach.

I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the logic for saving the Product with it's corresponding sizes/prices doesn't belong in your Controller, but in your Model (or some intermediate data layer).

As for your issue: you can only save pivot relations to a record that already has an id, ie. one that has already been saved to the database. Also, the `sync()` method on the belongsToMany class is meant for saving multiple relations by ids, and accepts a boolean as a second argument (whether to detach or not, default is true).

In this case you should do a foreach over the array of sizes, an `attach()` each one, with it's price, to the parent model. Something like this:

ProductsController.php

```
public method store(Request $request)
{
    // call the create method on the model
    $product = Product::createForSizes(
        $request->only('name', 'sizes', 'prices')
    );

    return $product 
        ? redirect()->route('some.route')
        : redirect()->route('some.other.route');
}
```

Product.php

```
public static method createForSizes($name, array $sizes, array $prices)
{  
    // create and save a new instance of the model
    if(!$product = static::create(compact('name'))) {
        return false;
    }

    // attach each size, with it's price
    foreach($sizes as $index => $id) {
        $price = isset($prices[$index]) ? $prices[$index] : null;
        $product->sizes()->attach($id, compact('price'));
    }

    return $product;
}
```

Note: Laravel looks for pivot tables automatically if you name them as plural, in alphabetical order. So if you name your pivot table *products_sizes*, you can omit the table name from the relation method like so:

```
public function sizes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class)->withPivot('price');
}
```